# Running Jenkins without Tomcat, attempting to SSH

Tags: ssh, github, hudson, jenkins, centos

I am not running jenkins through tomcat; I am instead running it as... I don't really know. I installed it through yum, and I run it.

I pay for the development of around fifty small java applications, with at most three being built at a time.

I've been using GitHub to keep all my developers in touch with eachother, and it has been working great.  Only now, I've made some repos private - and Jenkins can no longer access them.
I have attempted to give it SSH keys; I did this by using "ssh-keygen" as root, authenticated with "ssh -T git@github.com", and then copied all files (Public, private, and known hosts) to /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh.

I thought this would be enough to allow Jenkins access to my organizations private repos (I own it, and I added the public key to my GitHub account) - but that does not seem to be sufficient.

Where was it I went wrong?

Comment: You published the keys to the corresponding github repositories?

Comment: I'm attempting to authorize Jenkins as my own GitHub account, which owns the organization that hosts the private repos.
Should work, right?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was not properly giving Jenkins SSH authentication.

I had to edit `/etc/passwd`, and give it shell access (Changing `/false` to `/bash`),

& `su jenkins`

`ssh-keygen`

Open up the new `.pub` file, paste that into github, and then all was well.